# Percentage that accounts for zero mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that selects a phone number, a count for inbound calls that were answered, a count for inbound calls that were missed, and then a formula for the percentage of calls answered.

Assuming the user has had inbound calls, this formula works great but if they have had no inbound calls at all, I get null. The idea is that if they have no inbound calls then they should have 100% as the formulation for percentage of answered calls.

How can I best modify this to keep the current functionality but account for users with zero inbound calls?

```
SELECT  phone
 , sum(if(calltype= 2,1,0) and answered = 1) as inboundAnswered
 , sum(if(calltype= 2,1,0) and answered = 0) as inboundMissed
 , round((sum(if(calltype= 2,1,0) and answered = 1))/(sum(if(calltype= 2, 1, 0))) * 100,2) as AnsweredPercentage -- This takes inbound answered calls and divides by total inbound calls
FROM
  phoneCalls;
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do that calculation, using 100% Standard SQL. Let the formula return NULL when no call is answered and convert it to 100 using Coalesce;

```
COALESCE(100.00 * sum(case when calltype = 2 and answered = 1 then 1 end)/
                  sum(case when calltype = 2 then 1 end), 100)
```